# How can i create Graph in android aplication?

Tags: android

How to Create **3d Graph(Like pie,line,scatter)** in android Application?

Comment: Orson Charts for Android: http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AChartEngine` is a good option for this, Free, OpenSource and have almost all type of graphs.
you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list), as well as demo application also.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is how it works here:

1. You try yourself.
2. If you come up with any
   problem/exception/thing you can't
   solve yourself, you ask.

Since you've tried nothing and don't provide any code, I'm affraid you'll get no acceptable answer.

---

If you want to draw graphs and things like that, have a look at the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) (some [Android example](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4744c7cd9fd7c20d?pli=1)).

Comment: Actually, that's not how it works here; just how it should work!   And people should get punished for helping the lazy/clueless.